# How can I customize date and time format in ngx-mat-datetime-picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material2, date-pipe

I am working on Angular7 and its compatible **ngx-mat-datetime-picker**. It works as expected.

Want to customize the format:

**Actual:** `mm/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss`
**Expected:** `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Currently I don't find any option for formatting.

I tried something like this in template `value="{{ mydate | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' }}`

But not working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a custom adapter and specify the custom formats

```
const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'l, LTS'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  }
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NgxMatDateAdapter,
      useClass: CustomNgxDatetimeAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, NGX_MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    { provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS }
  ],
})
export class CustomNgxDateTimeModule { }
```

Please find the CustomNgxDatetimeAdapter.ts from the below gist

https://gist.github.com/nandhakumargdr/635af05419793e15f3758656ddd1ef39

[image]

Have tested it. It is working!

Comment: Let me know if you need the CustomNgxDatetimeAdapter class. I'll update the answer with the CustomNgxDatetimeAdapter code.

Comment: Please add CustomNgxDatetimeAdapter class

Comment: Edited the answer please find the gist

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nandhakumargdr/635af05419793e15f3758656ddd1ef39 - Anyway I'm attaching it here.

Comment: @NandhakumarAppusamy Could you please post a full working example? And is it possible to switch between local time and UTC at runtime?

Comment: It is working, Thank you for saving the day. Extremely thank you.

Comment: What if you change the locale dynamically? is it not stuck on this format?

Comment: yes, how to we achieve for changing the locale dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Create a constant: (insert your preferred format)

```
export const DATE_TIME_FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'l, LT',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'l, LT',
    monthYearLabel: 'MM yyyy',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  }
```

Provide:

```
{provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_TIME_FORMAT}
```

result (with my format removing the seconds):

```
9/4/2020, 1:11 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find more examples here https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/27

Comment: Is it be possible to customize the ngx-mat-datetime-picker to be used as a datetime range component ( from ... to) ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution i found

```
import {
      // modules
      NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
      NgxMatDateFormats,
      NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
    } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
    import {NgxMatMomentModule, NGX_MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular-material-components/moment-adapter';
    
    export const MOMENT_DATETIME_WITH_SECONDS_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
    
    // If using Moment
    const CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
    dateInput: MOMENT_DATETIME_WITH_SECONDS_FORMAT,
    },
    display: {
    dateInput: MOMENT_DATETIME_WITH_SECONDS_FORMAT,
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
    };
    
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    NgxMatMomentModule,
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
    ],
    exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    NgxMatMomentModule,
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
    ],
    providers: [
    // values
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}},
    {provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS},
    {provide: NGX_MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}},
    ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```